`sched_setaffinity` does not prevent scheduler to change to a CPU core not in cpuset
I'm working on an MPI application, in which each MPI process (based on its rank) is scheduled onto a specific CPU core.
Assuming to use OpenMPI implementation, to do so, --bind-to none is passed to mpirun (after have taken care to disable any affinity conflicts that might come from SLURM or other runtimes). This should assing a cpuset to each MPI process thread where all the CPU cores are ON.
Then, in the application code, a call to sched_setaffinity() is made, where each MPI process computes its CPU core.
Affinity is set as such:
CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(cpu, &cpuset);

Then, towards the end (after a time where we are sure the process has been preempted and re-scheduled), as a double check, each MPI process calls sched_getcpu() to check whether the CPU core ID matches the desired one.
Check which fails, meaning that the scheduler has put each MPI process thread onto a different CPU core than the one (THE ONLY ONE) present in the cpuset assigned via sched_setaffinity.
How comes?
